Application of Stone-Weierstrass theorem to linear combinations of real exponential functions
Theorem 7.32 in Rudin's PMA gives the Stone-Weierstrass theorem as follows:

7.32 Theorem: Let $A$ be an algebra of real continuous functions on a compact set $K$. If $A$ separates points in $K$ and if $A$
vanishes at no point of $K$, then the uniform closure $B$ of $A$
consists of all real continuous functions on $K$.

I wonder if the theorem applies to the set of linear combinations of real exponential functions on an interval $K=[0,R]$:
$$A = \{ f \in C(K, \mathbb{R}) : f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i e^{-\lambda_i t} \text{ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ and $c_i,\lambda_i\in\mathbb R$}\}$$
As far as I understand it, $A$ is an algebra and satisfies the hypothesis of the theorem above, so that, for any continuous function $g:K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
there exists a sequence $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of members of $A$ such that:
$\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k (t) = g(t)$ uniformly.
Am I missing something? Is my conclusion correct?

You did not state the definition of $A$ correctly.  $c_i$'s and $\lambda_i$'s are fixed or varying?

I tried to make your statement more precise. You are right that Stone-Weierstraß implies that $A$ is uniformly dense.

@geetha290krm, they are varying.

With the corrected definition of $A$, everything is fine.
